# How to make PhpStorm resolve files without extensions

Tags: phpstorm

For my website I have a .htaccess file that redirects `example.com/folder/page` to `example.com/folder/page.php`. Because of this all my links have the filename without the `.php`.

Is there any way to get PhpStorm to recognise this and a) not give me a "File Reference Problem" error and b) recognise these files when it does refractors and usage searches?